# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on window?

Tags: android, vision

java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

I've searched and tried this way a lot. 
To sum up the way I tried.

First. set environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS 
Second. gcloud auth application-default login(gcloud download and cmd)
Third. create api key and input static final String CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY

Errors continue to occur again and again..
There are many things to consider.
OAuth token..But it will be not answer.

i want to make image web detecter, but blocked, by certification phase.
plz help me..i want to be happy;

java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:132)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:100)
        at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:59)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:140)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.create(GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.java:84)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.createStub(ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.java:120)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:136)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:117)
        at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:108)
        at org.techtown.webfilter.MainActivity.detectWebDetections(MainActivity.java:152)
        at org.techtown.webfilter.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:107)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4577)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4626)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)